# Show $\frac{1}{|x-y|^{p}}-\frac{1}{|x|^{p}}\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ for fixed real y

Tags: real-analysis

This is homework so no answers please

Show $\frac{1}{|x-y|^{p}}-\frac{1}{|x|^{p}}\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ for fixed real y
where $|p|< \frac{1}{2}$.

Any strategies?

Attempt:

I will type as I go, I am just curious to see strategies suggested.

I tried the usual ones i.e. Holder, Jensens, Minkowski, linear interpolation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Locally it will be in $L^2({\mathbb R})$ when each term is, which gives $p < {1 \over 2}$.

For integrating the square when $|x|$ is large, the idea is that since by the mean value theorem $\frac{1}{|x-y|^{p}}-\frac{1}{|x|^{p}} = -p\frac {y} {|x - y^*|^{p+1}}$ for some $y^*$ between $0$ and $y$, one has  $\big|\frac{1}{|x-y|^{p}}-\frac{1}{|x|^{p}}\big| \sim \frac{|y|} {x^{p+1}}$, so that the square will be integrable if $2(p + 1) > 1$ or $p > -{1 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The result is false for $p=1/2$, since $1/|x|$ is not integrable at $0$.

If $p<1/2$, you only have to worry about integrability at $\infty$. Use the Mean Value Theorem. You will find the condition $p>-1/2$.

Comment: yeah I meant  $|p|< \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You meant other way. Because $\frac{1}{|x|^{\frac{1}{4}}}$ is well behaved at infinity.

Comment: and explodes at zero. So not there yet.